# Multiple class inheritance... for members? - swift5+

Tags: swift, class, protocols, swift5

So Swift question, I know I cant inherit multiple classes or structs... so how can I accomplish this task in swift? 5+

```swift
class shape {
var mType: String;
}

class box: shape{
 var mWidth: Int;
 var mHeight: Int;
}

/// RealityKit/arKit base class
class object: box, Entity, HasModel, HasCollision {
var someStuff: String;
}
```

Can any1 suggest any workflow/idea of how can I do this? I want to have a base class with certain details that will be inherited by everything in my app. The problem starts that some objects will need to inherit from both my own base class & swift base class. In which case I have 2 class inheritance and that's something swift doesn't do... Ideas?

TIA
Regards
Dariusz

Comment: Swift is more oriented to Protocol than Inheritance. `HasModel`, `HasCollision` might be protocols? It's unclear what they mean.

Comment: @Larme yes they are protocols. But protocol can't have member can it? So how can I have multiple object-level-based member-data holders like in the example?

Comment: “… will be inherited by everything in my app”, I don’t think this is a good path to take.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well I need a base class with prebuild variables, like name, id, type, etc etc on every object. So that I can always access object data/its common details that any object would have in the app. How can I do this in swift?

Comment: You need a singleton or a shared type

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Singelton is for 1 instance of an object in the app as far as I remember. I need thousands if not millions of objects...

Comment: Composition over inheritance, what if your types had a shape rather than being a shape

Comment: @Shadowrun what do you mean, can you show an example?

Comment: Ok I misread your earlier comment but still, multilevel inheriting is not the way to go.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so how can I solve this issue? How can I have base class with members that can be accessed on any object I have passed as Any. Say 
```
var obj = sender as! myBase
print(obj.mName) 
```
?

Answer (score 0):

You should instead be using Components. For example:

```swift
struct ShapeComponent: Component {
  var mType: String
}
struct BoxComponent: ShapeComponent {
  var mWidth: Int
  var mHeight: Int
}
```

It's unclear what you want to do with the box and shape classes, but if you just want to store data:

```swift
var boxEnt = ModelEntity(mesh: ..., materials: [...])
boxEnt.components[ShapeComponent.self] = ShapeComponent(mType: "box")
boxEnt.components[BoxComponent.self] = BoxComponent(mWidth: 1, mHeight: 1)
```

---

Or if you want to use the previously recommended RealityKit structure:

```swift
protocol HasShape: Entity {}
protocol HasBox: HasShape {}

extension HasShape {
  var shape: ShapeComponent? {
    get { self.components[ShapeComponent.self] }
    set { self.components[ShapeComponent.self] = newValue }
  }
}
extension HasBox {
  var box: BoxComponent? {
    get { self.components[BoxComponent.self] }
    set { self.components[BoxComponent.self] = newValue }
  }
}

class BoxObject: Entity, HasBox, HasModel, HasCollision {}
```

---

Class properties are not recommended in RealityKit